# Как сделать чат на PHP + MySQL?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, знатоки. Как сделать чат на PHP + MySQL на сайте. Заранее спасибо. )

Comment: А вы PHP + MySQL знаете? Что конкретно у Вас не получается?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iframe.php::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout("window.location.reload()",5000);//Обновление раз в 5 секунд
</script>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['message'])){
  $sql = "insert into `messages` (`message`) values ('".$_POST['message']."')";
  mysql_query($sql);
}
$sql = "select `message` from `messages` where 1 order by id desc";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
 printf("<div>%s</div>",$row->message);
}
?>
</body>
```

...
chat.php::

```
<body>
<iframe name='chatWindow' id='chatWindow' src='iframe.php'>Чатик</iframe>
<form action='iframe.php' method='post' target='chatWindow'>
<input type='text' name='message'>
<input type='submit' />
</form> 
</body>
```

Самый простой чат. Апгрейдить можно до бесконечности, принцип - изложен.
P.S. Редактор опять глючит. Кто-то обещал, что я скоро проникнусь его удобством. Так сложно CKEdit поставить или что-то типа?

Comment: Чего он глючит-то?) Достаточно было теги php правильно поставить)

Comment: Чат, вроде, не глючит. А редактор - да. Регулярно не реагирует на кнопку "преобразовать в код", при попытке редактировать области с кодом швыряет курсор в неизвестном направлении... итп. Управление по простоте и интуитивности напоминает vi: пищит и портит.

Comment: Хм, в опере такое было, выкинул оперу) (не только поэтому)

Тут ничего не могу сказать, это к админам, да.

Про чат: если добавить поле ввода имени (ну или только зареганных пускать) и в скрипт фрейма добавить обновление раз в ~5 сек - будет даже круто) Можно еще форме сделать target="my-iframe" и будет похоже на аякс)

Comment: и в скрипт фрейма добавить обновление раз в ~5 сек || упс! забыл. =) Для этого там скрипт и висит... спасибо. =)  

Насчет регистрации - тут полно сообщений. И как регистрацию, и как openID

Comment: Спасибо ша проверю )

Comment: %s",$row->message); } ?>  у меня такую ошибку выбивает((

Comment: Влад, у вас php включен?)

Comment: Ну лан, с эти протупил)) Но у меня сообщения не отправляет, отправляет окна для чата в окно для чата, как поставить зеркало на впротив зеркала(

Comment: Сколько у вас файлов? И что расположено в каждом?

Comment: У меня два файла. первый iframe , второй сам чат, как показано в ответе!

Comment: acrion у формы надо поменять на iframe.php.
Это я туплю.